# What exactly is a "forus packet"?

Tags: switch, router

I've been trying to read up on a debug output I received with "FORUS FALSE" on it and tried looking online for that, and then I found just a little bit about a forus packet saying it's a packet destined for the router itself but I think I saw this output on a switch?

I'm not able to find any solid information on this? Could someone please explain what a forus packet is and what forus false is supposed to be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "forus" packet.  The term is a Cisco internal debugging flag that means the packet is destined for the router itself.  In debugging messages, if a packet is destined for the router, it is indicated by "FORUS true", or "FORUS False" if not.

The internal flag is named "FORUS" as in "the packet was meant 'For Us.'"

Comment: OH. For us! So this would appear in the debugging logs of any packets flowing outward, yes?